# DB::select() - how to get array of arrays instead array of collections

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections, laravel-5.7

I have raw query: `$data = DB::select('...');`.

As a result, `$data` is an array of collections:

```
array:999 [
  0 => {#331
    +"v": 1
  }
  1 => {#328
    +"v": 2
  }
  2 => {#332
    +"v": 3
  }
  ...
]
```

I want to get array of arrays instead:

```
array:999 [
  0 => array:1 [
    "v" => 2
  ]
  1 => array:1 [
    "v" => 3
  ]
  ...
]
```

I can iterate over `$data` with casting to `array`:

```
$arr = [];
foreach ($data as $i) {
    $arr[] = (array)$i;
}

//other way

$arr = array_map(function ($i) {
    return (array)$i;
}, $data);
```

but it seems like not optimal way for large data sets.

Answer (score 0):

Use toArray() method for collections.
You can call 
`$data = DB::select(...); 
$data = collect($data)->toArray();`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-toarray

Comment: You can't call `->get()` on array. `DB::select()` returns an array not collection.

Comment: @Tarasovych edited. You should be able to convert the array to collection with collect() and then call toArray() on it since it converts all the nested objects too. Or preferably use something like DB::table() .... ->get() to get collection and then convert that to array

Comment: It's too costly for large amounts of data. I want to get array of arrays right after `DB::select();` instead converting to collection and back.

Comment: @Tarasovych then use array_map as you suggested. PHP 7 is quite fast, time it takes to convert it with array_map should be quite small compared to how long the database query takes.